Lie algebra of Hamiltonian (1,0) vector fields on 4-manifold
I have encountered a certain Lie subalgebra of the Lie algebra of vector fields on a 4-manifold that is also a complex manifold, distinct from the well-known Lie algebra of holomorphic vector fields. It feels that it must be known, and I would be grateful for any references or comments.
The Lie algebra is as follows. Let $M$ be a Riemannian 4-manifold which I assume has an integrable SU(2) structure. In particular, I assume that there is a covariantly constant holomorphic top form $\Omega\in \Lambda^{(2,0)}$. Let $\Omega^{\mu\nu}$ be the corresponding bivector. Let me consider the vector field $X^\mu_{\phi} = \Omega^{\mu\nu} \partial_\nu \phi$, where $\phi$ is a function on $M$. Then a computation shows that $[X_{\phi_1},X_{\phi_2}] = X_{[\phi_1,\phi_2]}$ where $[\phi_1,\phi_2] = \Omega^{\mu\nu} \partial_\mu \phi_1 \partial_\nu\phi_2$. So, such vector fields form a Lie algebra. It is clear that these vector fields are $(1,0)$, but they are in general not holomorphic.
Has this Lie algebra been encountered before and if yes does it have some standard name?

I have realised that what I have described is just the Poisson algebra of functions on $M$, with the Poisson bivector being the $(2,0)$ bivector of some complex structure on $M$. Also, the vector fields I described span all of $(1,0)$ vector fields, and so the Lie algebra is just that of $(1,0)$ vector fields.
